# Make child height update height of his siblings

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way to define childHeight as more important than its siblings and propagate its size to (less important) siblings.

Consider this layout

```
<RelativeLayout
  match_parent,match_parent>

    <FrameLayout 
      match_parent,match_parent>

        <ViewA
          this view size is important and its siblings should have same size, set on Runtime.
          layout_gravity="center"/>

        <ViewB
          match_parent,match_parent
          layout_gravity="center"
          (should have the size of ViewB)  />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I know how to do it using ConstrainLayout but I am asking just out of curiosity

```
<ConstraintLayout>
      <ViewA
       wrap_content,wrap_content
       constraint_to="parent"/>

       <ViewB
          0dp,0dp
          constraint_to="ViewA"
          layout_gravity="center"
          (should have the size of ViewA)  />
</ConstraintLayout>
```

***Use case*** I have cameraView (ViewA) and cameraOverlay (ViewB). ViewA changes it's size according to user preference (16:9 | 4:3...) and ViewB (has some alpha) must always overlap whole ViewA.

Edit: Forgot to add that I don't want to change size of viewB manually

Comment: Did you try using LinearLayout and weight?

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil Linear wouldn't really allow me to overlap one another. But it would work in other scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you change the height/width of viewA programmatically. So you have the height and width resources available.

To others who have the same problem, to set the height of the View:

```
viewB.getLayoutParams().height = heightViewA;
viewB.getLayoutParams().width = widthViewB;
```

Hope this helps.

**Important.** If you're setting the height after the layout has already been 'laid out', make sure you also call:

```
viewB.requestLayout()
```

Another option is to use 
`RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
       wrap_content,wrap_content    
>
      <ViewA
       wrap_content,wrap_content
       constraint_to="parent"/>

       <ViewB
          match_parent,match_parent
          constraint_to="ViewA"
          layout_gravity="center"
          (should have the size of ViewA)  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in `RelativeLayout`  you can overlay them.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I don't want to change size of viewB manually, but thanks